# Why use ${@+"$@"} in shell scripts?

Tags: linux, posix, sh

An example:

```
foo() {
    for i in ${@+"$@"}; do
        echo $i
    done
}
```

I understand that `${parameter+word}` results in the expansion of `word` if `parameter` is set. But why not just use `for i in "$@"; do`? I'm sure there is some benefit, but can anyone make an example?

Thanks!

Comment: I think (but cannot confirm) that this is a workaround for some shells that do not correctly handle `$@`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the POSIX standard, `"$@"` should expand to nothing if `$@` is not set. However, the original Bourne shell expands this to a single empty string. `${@+"$@"}` will expand to nothing if `$@` is not set in either shell.

Source: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/bourne_args/

Comment: To clarify: this mechanism used to be necessary, but it is a relic of a foregone era.

Comment: "foregone"?  Perhaps "bygone".  I don't know why I didn't just say it's obsolete.  If you are using `/bin/sh` on Solaris 2.8, this sort of thing may still be necessary , but that's several years old.  (2008?)

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up for me. It was from a script used on and old HP-UX, which explains the need.

Answer (score -1):

when `$@` is an empty string `""`, `${@+"$@"}` produce nothing, but `"$@"` produce `""`, check it:

```
foo() {
    for i in ${@:+"$@"}; do
        echo XXX: $i
    done
}

bar() {
    for i in "$@"; do
        echo XXX: $i
    done
}

echo foo:
foo ""
echo bar:
bar ""
```

`foo` doesn't call echo, but `bar` calls it

Comment: `foo` doesn't call `echo` because you used `${@:+"$@"}`, not `${@+"$@"}` (you added the colon to the expansion). Omit the colon, and `foo` behaves the same as bar.